# What would be the right logic to reuse properties and methods between 2 Angular Components and Services?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have 2 Angular Components ProductComponent and ImportListComponent
I have created a model for Product as follows:

```
import { Image } from './image.model';
import { Category } from './category.model';

export class Product {
  constructor(
    public id: number, 
    public name: string, 
    public priceRange: string, 
    public description: string, 
    public imageUrl: string,
    public initialPrice?: number,
    public importListPrice?: number,
    public category?: Category,
    public inStock?: boolean,
    public amountInStock?: number,
    public sku?: string, 
    public images?: Image[]
  ) {}
}
```

I also created a model for ImportList that extends the product model as follows:

```
import { Product }  from './product.model';
import { Image }    from './image.model';
import { Category } from './category.model';

export class ImportList extends Product {
  constructor(
    id: number, 
    name: string, 
    priceRange: string, 
    description: string, 
    imageUrl: string, 
    initialPrice?: number, 
    importListPrice?: number, 
    category?: Category, 
    inStock?: boolean, 
    amountInStock?: number, 
    sku?: string, 
    images?: Image[]
  ) {
    super(id, name, priceRange, description, imageUrl, initialPrice, importListPrice);
  }
}
```

The difference between Product and ImportList is that the price, description, and name can be changed before they are added to ImportList and pushed to the store.
We do not want the changed properties to affect or mutate the original Product. Hence the need to create the separate ImportList. Each user on the system can have different ImportList. But they have access to the same base Product. 
The service and logic to get new products from the API are like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  private productsUrl = 'api/products'; // URL to web api 

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.productsUrl)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data as Product[])
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

How can I make properties in the model classes reusable?
And How can I make methods in the ProductService reusable by the ImportListService and methods in the ProductComponent reusable by the ImportListComponent class?

Because when I tried to use the ImportList model in the ImportListComponent just for a test like so:

```
export class ImportListComponent {
  importList : ImportList[
    new ImportList()
  ];
}
```

I got a confusing and not very clear error saying `Type 'new () => ImportList' cannot be used as an index type import ImportList`. Even when ImportList was already imported. How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so -  interface crash course, if you decide to go that route.

```
 importList : ImportList[ new
```

Two problems with how you started it. You can't instantiate an array and type it in the same declaration. You'd have to do

```
importList : ImportList[] =  [  ...declaration here... ]
```

the other problem would be trying to use the 'new' keyword as i mentioned. Just build the objects literally. If you wanted to do it all in one declaration, it would look like :

```
importList : ImportList[] = [
      { id: 1, 
        name: 'somename',
        priceRange: '10$-15$,
        description: 'something',
        imageurl: 'someurl',
        originalProduct: this.variableNameOfOtherProduct, 
      },
      { id: 2, 
        name: 'othername'.    ... and so on and so on... 
      }
 ]
```

The above actually wouldn't work either with the way I have the interfaces written, because it still needs an initial price and import price, both paramteters that aren't marked as optional. Typescript would give an error "Can't set to type - Import List - Property 'initialPrice', and 'importPrice' are missing' or something like that.

So you can just also set those two parameters as optional in the interface, or alternatively, make sure to provide them when creating the items. If you look at many of the angular core interfaces, they often set nearly every parameter to optional. This allows great flexibility to add to your object incrementally as needed, but still have strong type checking. I do the same thing in my interfaces, I often set every parameter to optional except maybe one or two of them, the absolute minimum needed to identify it uniquely. In your case that might be the id. So every other property name could have a question mark after its name, except that one, and you'd only be *required* to specify an ID when you create it, and could add the other properties later. It may seem cumbersome to have to literally type out the property names for every object rather than just including their value, but it makes the code infinitely more readable/maintainable.

One thing to be aware of, is that typescript will be confused if you try to reference a property on an object of type  that hasn't yet been instantiated. So if you created:

```
     [
        { id: 85, name 'somename'  }
       ...
     ]
```

as the first item in your this.importList array, (and this is assuming everything except id and name are optional), and then you tried to add the priceRange property by writing

```
 this.importList[0].priceRange = '10$ - 15$';
```

It would get confused because that property hasn't been created yet. In these cases you just need to use javascript 'bracket notation' for adding new properties to existing objects. It is done similar to how array values are referenced, but with the string name of the property instead of a number inside.

Simple example, If you had some object

```
 this.bob : BobInterface = { id: 1 } ;
```

and wanted to add a property named 'age' to it, even though the age property may be specified in a Bob interface, it hasnt' been created yet, so you can't go

```
 this.bob.age = 50;
```

You'd have to write

```
 this.bob['age'] = 50;
```

This instantiates and assigns the property at the same time.

So in your case, if you need to add additional properties to the list after its been declared, you would write something like

```
  this.importList[0]['priceRange']= '10$ - 15$';
```

The first set of brackets is specifying which array item of importList we are referring to, the second set of brackets is the property of the corresponding ImportList item.

After a property has been declared like that, you can just write,

```
  this.importList[0].priceRange;
```

like normal, and typescript will know what to do.

SO - back to the point... to add existing products to the ImportList, you'd just need to refer to their identifier as the value for the originalProduct property.

If you initialize the list without them, you can add them later by:

```
this.importList[0]['originalProduct']= referenceToProductObject;
```

But if you're including it all when originally declaring the array values, you just write

```
 [
  ....
  {... priceRange: '10$ - 15$', originalProduct: this.originalProductList[25]  .... } 
 ....
 ]
```

In the example above I've assumed originalProduct was in a different array at index # 25, it could be anywhere though, as long as its an object of type Product.

I hope this makes sense. It can be a little tricky at first bc classes tend to provide more structure - you typically know all the properties of a class have been instantiated, so you can usually refer to them without bracket notation. However, using interfaces somewhat loosely like this can becomes a much more powerful way to deal with objects - get extreme flexibility *and* strong type checking. Best of both worlds.

EDIT :  Also, could be a good time to learn about creating a 'Map' in typescript . You can declare an object in your component like this

```
  importedProductsMap : { [index:string] : ImportList } = {};
```

The above can be very powerful. It creates an object and tells typescript that the object will only hold ImportList objects, and those ImportList objects will all be referenced by some identifier, which can be any string .  There could be 1million of them in the object or zero. Doesn't matter. As long as they are ImportList objects named via strings, they can be included. This provides a great alternative to arrays, as they can hold many items like an array, but you can reference individual items with their id or names (or anything really, as long as its unique for each item) directly instead of their numerical position in an array, which can be pretty arbirtary.

so if you were inside a for loop, where you'd normally be adding ImportList objects to an array with

```
 this.importList.push(aNewImportListObject);
```

You could add that to the importedProductsMap you defined above with:

```
 this.importedProductsMap[aNewImportListObject.name] = aNewImportListObject;
```

This adds the ImportList Object to your map, using its own name as its identifier (names would have to be unique in this case, but just for an example we can forget about that). Then you can reference it like

```
 console.log(this.importedProductsMap.someName.id);
```

and it would log the id property of that object. If you have a list of objects that you are constantly referring to and tweaking, its muuuuch easier to use a map than an array. Prevents you from having to constantly iterate through lists and find matches.

I dunno why i wrote all this but I sincerely hope it helps.

And the crazy thing about all of this... it doesn't actually make a bit of difference in the resulting code generated by the compiler. Interfaces compile to nothing... they basically disappear, they are just there to help you interact with objects smartly, write more structured code, and get full advantage of static type checking.

Comment: mannn it does help. Thank you so much, for taking the time to explain in depth. I really appreciate you.

Comment: one important addendum ... which has been the source of weeks of frustration for me on multiple occasions...

If you add the originalProduct to the ImportList using a variable/reference to some Product that already exists elsewhere, it will work fine, but be aware that when you alter that Product where it lived originally - like, let's say it was it was in an array of Product objects. If you changed something about that product inside that array,  the product "copy" inside the totally separate ImportList object will *also* be changed. This took me so long to figure out and drove me nuts.

Comment: bc Javascript passes objects by "reference", not by "value", so its not actually copying the Product - its just telling ImportList object where it can find that product in memory. Still pointing to the same object. This can be good or bad depending on what you're doing. If you want the Products to always stay in sync when they are updated - good. If you want a snapshot of it when it was created - bad. This doesn't happen for primitives like strings and numbers, but happens for objects / arrays. 

See: https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-deep-copy-aka-clone-objects-using-typescript

Answer (score 1):

Since the classes have no custom logic or methods, I would just define interfaces, and give the importlist a new property of type Product so it can store a copy of its original product

```
export interface Product {
    id: number, 
    name: string, 
    priceRange: string, 
    description: string, 
    imageUrl: string,
    initialPrice?: number,
    importListPrice?: number,
    category?: Category,
    inStock?: boolean,
    amountInStock?: number,
    sku?: string, 
    images?: Image[] 
}

export interface ImportList {
    id:number,
    name:string.
    priceRange: string,
    description: string,
    imageUrl: string
    initialPrice: number; 
    importListPrice: number;
    originalProduct?: Product;
}
```

using the Angular4 HttpClient, you can type check the JSON as its being read:

```
 http.get<ImportList>('/apipath/here').subscribe(data => { 
     this.productList = data;
 });
```

That's asumming the JSON is close enough to the ImportList interface to type properly. If it needs to be modified beforehand, just use get() instead of a typed get

Comment: Hi @diopside thanks for your answer. Sadly I'm using the in-memory-api by angular here - https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/122, which doesn't support HttpClient yet. So I still need to know how the service would look like. And I'm not sure if the Interface would still work for my logic above, especially when it's time to make reference to the interface at the ProductComponent and ImportListComponent class as well as on the service level where you get to receive the data from the api. 
Is it possible to make use of the interface in a service?

Comment: For use case of just storing and accessing data, classes and interfaces can be used virtually identically.

Comment: The reason you are getting that error, is because you're trying to create an array and fill it with a single value at the same time, which ends up being syntacticaly identical to the way array indices are referenced in JS.  It thinks you are trying to access some element of an array at index "new ImportList()" and gets confused. Alternatives would be creating an empty array first and pushing new values into it w/ Array.push, or doing 

importList = new Array(1).fill(new ImportList());    (1 being the length of your new array)

Comment: Also, based on how you have written the code,  new ImportList() won't ever work, because it has required parameters in its constructor. You are trying to instantiate a new list without providing any parameters to the constructor, so it doesn't know what to do. Interfaces give you a lot more flexibility in this regard.

Comment: So I reformated the 2 models, exactly the way it is above, but still can't use Product in the ImportListComponent. This still give the exact same error i mentioned above. 
importList : ImportList[
    new ImportList(1, 'somename', '$10 - $15', 'something', 'someurl', how do i use the originalProduct here?),
    new ImportList(2, 'somename', '$10 - $15', 'something', 'someurl', how do i use the originalProduct here?)
  ];
How do you think I can use the OriginalProduct while creating a new ImportList? I just want to be able to modify the original product but have it not mutate the original.

Comment: you'll never use 'new' when using interfaces, that's one key difference. You can just build object literals. Its hard to show without formatting, so i will leave an additional answer.

Comment: to clarify, is the ImportList being created first? And it would just be storing a 'snapshot' of itself when it is created? Or are Products created first and then ImportLists are adapted from products?

Comment: Product is created first and ImportList is adapted from Products.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152672/discussion-between-mayorsanmayor-and-diopside).